# Fake Class for Development Environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a service that runs on the production machine that I access through a service class in my app.

Because of licensing costs, I'd like to fake that service for my test and development environments.

How can I load a different class definition depending on Environment in my rails app?

Comment: Is the issue related to the service calling an API? Or does the license prohibit your running the code at all on more than one machine?

Comment: It queries a binary running on the server.  We aren't allowed to install that binary on staging / my dev environment.

Answer (score 0):

Use Rails.env in your implementation

```
def my_method
  if Rails.env.production?
    Model.production_method
  else
    Model.development_method
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't recommend ever running the `production?` or similar methods for feature detection. You should instead set up environment variables that instruct the app on which logic to run. So instead, you'd have something like `FEATURE_X=true` in production and `FEATURE_X=false` in the other environments.

Comment: @ChrisPeters well yes, you can do that.

Comment: It's not the "Rails.env.production?" part i'm asking about.   I want to know how to included a different version of the class for those environments.

Comment: @Will What are different versions of a class? Different classes? You can use another class in the else path of Deepak's example.

Comment: trouble with this type of solution is I would have to do it in many places in my app's code

Answer (score 0):

If I catch your explanation you have class that does something based on a system feature, not an API or similar. Meaning that you might be using a gem that has a class that is loaded only on the required enviroments:

```
gem 'expensive_service', group: :production
```

And this gem seems to have a class: ExpensiveService, that is not available in your other environments. So what you need to do is create a class that overwrites this gem and is loaded only in the environments you define it.

```
#lib/expensive_service.rb
class ExpensiveService
  def foo
  end
end
```

And then in your `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.autoload_paths << "#{Rails.root}/lib/expensive_service"
```

More info:

[Autoload Paths](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoloading-and-require)

[Configuring](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html)